# Round to 3 decimal places if needed otherwise round to 2 decimal places in Pythonic manner

Tags: python

I want to take a float and convert to a 2 decimal or 3 decimal place percentage. However, I only want to show 3 decimal places if 2 decimal places would display the percentage as `0.00%`.

```py
>>> x = 0.0001
>>> f'{x:,.2%}'
'0.01%'
>>> y = 0.00001
>>> f'{y:,.2%}'
'0.00%'
```

How can I have it show 3 decimal places for the case of `y` in a **Pythonic** manner? Is there some way I can avoid conditionals?

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in formatting option that does this, so you need to use a conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested f-strings! I choose you!

```py
In [42]: x=1e-4

In [43]: f'{x:{",.2%" if x >= 1e-4 else ",.3%"}}'
Out[43]: '0.01%'

In [44]: x=1e-5

In [45]: f'{x:{",.2%" if x >= 1e-4 else ",.3%"}}'
Out[45]: '0.001%'
```